# Script to mail multiple files as independant email attachments

Tags: bash, email, scripting

I'm looking to mail several pdf's that are located in a single directory via the mail command.  Each email should only contain one PDF file as an attachment.

Can you please provide a template on how to send each PDF via mail, one by one?  Ideally Bash or AppleScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use mutt or uuencode

```
recipient="user@somewhere.com"
for file in *.pdf
do
    mutt -s "subject" -a "$file" $recipient < message.txt
    # uuencode "$file" "$file" | mail -s "subject" $recipient  #using uuencode
done
```

Comment: @ghostdog74, I have nothing to try against, but the second example, the one commented, is simply uuencode enough?